# Xamarin Forms Listview issue

Tags: xamarin.forms

am new to using Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin Forms development and need help with an issue that I have encountered.

I am using an ObservableCollection to populate a list view.

```
ObservableCollection<TrayRow> TrayRowList = new ObservableCollection<TrayRow>();
```

TrayRow is a simple class that I have defined, i.e.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Testing
{
    class TrayRow
    {
        public String Trolly { get; set; }
        public string AssignedTo { get; set; }   
    }
}
```

so 2 properties of the class. And there are 2 columns in the list view.

Here's the code for populating the list view.

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
      foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
      {
           //Fill  listbox
           this.TrayRowList.Add(new TrayRow { Trolly = row["Trolly"].ToString(), 
                AssignedTo = row["AssignedTo"].ToString() });

      }
      ListviewTrays.ItemsSource = this.TrayRowList;
}
```

All of this works fine using the Debug configuration. The 2 columns of data are shown in the list view. But when i change to the Release configuration, the 2 columns in the list view are shown but the data is only populated in the first column!

Is this a build setting?

Comment: that's strange.  I would try adding some Console.Writeline to output your data to the log as your process it, then you can verify if it is a data issue or not

Comment: What is your first colum? Is `Trolly` or `AssignedTo`, I notice you used different format string for this two properties.Trolly is `String` , AssignedTo is `string`. please keep same format, then make a test.

Comment: yes i changed both to string. But still no joy. I even upgraded the Xamarin.Forms NuGet package to the latest version 4.7.0.1239. Still the same issue, i.e. the data is populated in column 2 in debug mode but not in release mode :-(

Comment: Can you use VS 2019 to make a test? Or could your share a demo about this issue.

Comment: Hi all, I have solved the issue but do not know why the changes that I have implemented have solved it!       In the Android's project properties, I have changed the linking from "Sdk and User Assemblies" to "None". This has fixed my problems. Any ideas why?

Comment: Linking was used to reduce the size of the application(it will remove the attribute types, it like a garbage collector)If you set the Linking to None, it will not remove any attribute types like your debug way.